# What's the meaning of "In-memory only" in the comment of UE's character type definition?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

\UE_5.0\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\GenericPlatform\GenericPlatform.h

```cpp
// A switchable character. In-memory only. Either ANSICHAR or WIDECHAR, depending on a licensee's requirements.
typedef WIDECHAR            TCHAR;
```

It's not just TCHAR, it's in the comments for all character types. What's the meaning of "In-memory only"?

Comment: "In-memory" usually means "Used in the program, but not stored to disk.".

Comment: @Aconcagua As I understand, they define their own `TCHAR` here, they do not use the Windows' definition.

Comment: @Aconcagua It's the other way around: `typedef WIDECHAR TCHAR;` means they use `WIDECHAR` as a basis to define `TCHAR`.

Comment: So we can't save a TCHAR to Disk?

Comment: @heapunderrun Oh, how dumb can one be, how didn't I notice??? Apparently having used `using X = Y;` for too long now :( – still naming is unlucky – now the other way round: It clashes with MS `TCHAR`.

Comment: @orange *'So we can't save a TCHAR to Disk?'* Well, sure you can. You just need to serve the right API. As C++, I'd provide function *overloads* for, one accepting ordinary `char`, one `wchar_t` (or whatever else they might define `WIDECHAR` to), each one mapping to the respective correct API. You could typedef `std::ofstream`/`std::wofstream` such to match the definition of `TCHAR` as well, e.g. `using OFStream = std::basic_ofstream<TCHAR>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreal uses platform definition files, such as `GenericPlatform.h`, `AndroidPlatform.h`, etc., to specify how certain aspects of the engine, like templated classes using platform-dependent integer sizes, or character widths, behave on different platforms.

So the same macro, i.e. `TCHAR`, on Windows and iOS, might mean a different underlying type, and related classes (such as `FString`) would then behave slightly differently on those platforms, representing values *in-memory* in a way that's better optimized for the underlying architecture.

However, on-disk data, such as a text file, should strive for cross-platform compatibility. So the same string on two platforms with different character lengths should be saved to disk in the same way. That's why such classes are serialized with an encoding and character length that are not necessarily the same as their in-memory representation.

For example, when you save an `FString` to a file with `FFileHelper::SaveStringToFile`, UE re-encodes its in-memory characters to on-disk characters of the type you specify (ANSI or UTF-8 or whatever), as it makes very little sense to directly save a file containing whatever `wchar_t` is (it's implementation specific and differs in bit length).